# Want to delete with HibernateUtils, but it throws exception

Tags: java, hibernate

I just want to delete vPref from my db, but it throws 
`caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Removing a detached instance models.Preference`

```
   public void valueChange(Property.ValueChangeEvent event) {
        switch ((SelectedDropdownItem) event.getProperty().getValue()) {
                    default:
                    if(vPref != null) {
                        HibernateUtils.delete(vPref);
                        vPref = null;
                    }
                    break;
```

the vPref cant be null, so I dont even know what the problem.

Comment: Are you sure you are within a transaction ? before you delete you have started a transaction ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot remove an instance which is detached from `hibernate`.
You need to first `load` the instance and then do any update operation on that instance.
See [link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-detached)

Comment: to delete, firstly I needed to reload it.
                            HibernateUtils.delete(HibernateUtils.findById(VPref.class, vPref.id));